# React hangs with _dereq_

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a problem which makes my page hang and I can see in Firebug the following line of React selected:

```
_dereq_-
```

---

```
[1]<()react-0.13.3.js (line 20)
_dereq_ = Object { type="object"}
module = Object { type="object"}
exports = Object { type="object"}
```

---

```
'use strict';
var EventPluginUtils = _dereq_(19);
```

Any idea or recommendation on this case?

Comment: Not a react issue, it's probably something to do with your bundler, are you using browserify, derequire, webpack or something similar?

Comment: Can you give me an example on this issue root cause? honestly, I use only pure React + JavaScript + JQuery and FireBug Add-on on firefox.

Comment: You're just including React as a script?

Comment: Yes, just include React as script, don't even use JSX parser neither. Each element component created using React.createClass, React.createElement

Comment: Can you show some code, including where the script is placed.

Comment: React JS and other JSs included by <script src...>
var App{};
(function(){
    App = React.createClass...
})();

Comment: I can see that, once I place <script src="react.js" it will hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conflict with FireBug

```
- Removed FireBug
```